# Low accuracy of object/face annotation in Google MLkit and other libraries

Tags: android, face-detection, google-mlkit

I downloaded the sample project from MLkit's official git(https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart), successfully installed it and got it running. The face contours appeared in the face detection mode. However, it is far from being accurate. I took the simplest and most notifiable (and also important) features like canthal index (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6408655/) as an example. I tried it on real people in the camera view and also photos printed out and put in front of the camera. **Surprisingly, everyone's canthal index ( calculated as the ratio of en-en to ex-ex) is between 0.38 to 0.40**. The sample pictures I used are of public figures ranging from Europeans to Central Asians to East Asians. Unbelievable but you can try it out yourself and see the results. I have a modified version (https://github.com/zhuofusong/FaceAnalysisApp/tree/main/android/mlkit%20vision) of the original mlkit's example project which adds a display of canthal index in the face detection mode when contour display is on.

Is this a defect? Then I looked into this issue further and found the landmarks ( or the contours) are very inaccurate around the eye area. No meaningful features or indices can be possibly calculated using landmarks of such quality. The angle between ex-en and the horizontal line is also very far off.

It is quite weird that Google's official MLkit example produces such coarse and wrong data. Is it NOT the case that the 1st feature on a face identified by any human being is all the indices related to eyes? The misleading contours pushed me to look for other solutions.

I Hope MLkit team can fix this inaccurate image annotation issue soon. This will enable other developers more quickly generate meaningful APIs that can be linked with other databases and knowledge bases.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input images (and sample output with the contour annotations)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I searched the 'canthal index'. In the [first-ranked paper](https://www.ajol.info/index.php/gjms/article/view/79169#:%7E:text=Canthal%20index%20was%2036.72%C2%B1,respectively%20for%20males%20and%20females.), the normal canthal index value is 0.36±0.03 and 0.36±0.05 according to the paper. Would that match the expectations?

ML Kit provides on-device ML models, which needs to balance model size, performance and accuracy. The accuracy is for-sure sacrificed to get better performance and smaller size on wide range of devices. We are working on new models to improve the accuracy / performance.